# Can't get resource bitmap sizes using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, wtl

I have an b/w bmp file. It's 8 BPP picture, size is 2048 * 2048. I create a new WTL project, go to "Resources" -> Import Bitmap -> select my bmp file -> give it `MYBITMAPID` id

Here is the code:

```
HBITMAP bm = ::LoadBitmap( _Module.GetModuleInstance(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(MYBITMAPID));
ATLASSERT(bm); // <--- Ok

SIZE sz;
BOOL res = ::GetBitmapDimensionEx(bm, &sz);
ATLASSERT(res); // <--- Ok

ATLASSERT(sz.cx && sz.cy); // <--- Not Ok
```

The debugger says both sizes are 0.

I tried

```
HBITMAP bm = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage( _Module.GetModuleInstance(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(MYBITMAPID), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_SHARED | LR_MONOCHROME);
```

and got the same result.

I could obtain the sizes with CBitmap class, but i would like to use winapi only for this operation.

How can i load bitmap from resources?

Comment: Any luck using [`GetObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932477.aspx) and a `BITMAP` structure?

Comment: Made an answer out of my comment.

Answer (score 3):

WTL offers you helpers for this:

```
CBitmap Bitmap = AtlLoadBitmap(MYBITMAPID);
SIZE Extent;
BOOL bGetSizeResult = Bitmap.GetSize(Extent);
```

Comment: This is not exactly what i need, but thank you for usefull info anyway!

Comment: What do you need then? It loads bitmap from resource and obtains its width and height. If you need underlying pure Win API function to do this - just step into the method with debugger, to fnid out it's doing it with `GetObject` API.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`GetObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932477.aspx) function and pass it a [`BITMAP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923934.aspx) structure to fetch a resource bitmap's size.